# DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un DataGridView de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi codigo

Al darle clic en el boton registrar hace esto:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvEstudiantes.Rows)
        {

            int indice = dgvEstudiantes.CurrentRow.Index;
            MessageBox.Show(""+indice);
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell objCheckBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)item.Cells[4];
            if (objCheckBox.Value == objCheckBox.TrueValue)
            {

                objAsistencia.IdCurso = int.Parse(cmbAsistenciaCurso.SelectedValue.ToString());
                objAsistencia.Estado = 1;
                objAsistencia.HorasVistas = int.Parse(txtHorasvistas.Text);
                objAsistencia.Fecha = dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Year + "-" + dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Month + "-" + dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Day;
                objAsistencia.registrarAsistencia();
                MessageBox.Show("Sirve boton");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("no sirve boton");
            }
        }
```

Pero el problema que presento es que el indice siempre muestra esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto el registro del documento 122222 nunca lo hace. Me podrían ayudar a que inicie en el 122222?

Comment: ¿Qué debería mostrar el `MessageBox`?

Comment: lo que no me queda claro es porque no usas ningun dato de la row seleccionada cuando defienes las propiedades de objAsistencia

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que usar la variable `item` que es la que itera por cada row para conocer el index

por eso use

```
MessageBox.Show(item.Index);
```

el el codigo quedaria

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvEstudiantes.Rows)
{

    MessageBox.Show(item.Index);
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell objCheckBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)item.Cells[4];
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(objCheckBox.Value))
    {

        objAsistencia.IdCurso = int.Parse(cmbAsistenciaCurso.SelectedValue.ToString());
        objAsistencia.Estado = 1;
        objAsistencia.HorasVistas = int.Parse(txtHorasvistas.Text);
        objAsistencia.Fecha = dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Year + "-" + dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Month + "-" + dtpFechaAsistencia.Value.Day;
        objAsistencia.registrarAsistencia();
        MessageBox.Show("Sirve boton");
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("no sirve boton");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplemente recorrer tu datagridview y obtener las filas que estan con el check  y luego saber sus posiciones o los valores que tiene cada celda:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvEstudiantes.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[4].Value == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(row.Index.ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El índice que indicas no influye en el comportamiento erróneo del código. Te muestra "2" porque ese es el registro seleccionado.

El problema creo que está aquí:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell objCheckBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)item.Cells[4];
if (objCheckBox.Value == objCheckBox.TrueValue)
```

Prueba:

```
CheckBox objCheckBox = (CheckBox) item.Cells[4].FindControl("NombreDeTuCheckBoxAsistencia");
if (objCheckBox.Checked)
```

El índice lo veo irrelevante, a menos que sea utilizado en otra parte y aún así te va a mostrar el registro seleccionado nada mas.

Answer (score 0):

Se utiliza item.Index ya que si utilizamos dgvEstudiantes.CurrentRow.Index da el indice que esta actualmente seleccionado en la aplicación.